# Difference between wake, poweron, and wakeorpoweron on pmset

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, cron, pmset

I'm trying to use [pmset](https://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/pmset.html) to wake my macbook before a cronjob is scheduled. The documentation says a scheduled event has a type that is "one of sleep, wake, poweron, shutdown, wakeorpoweron". My question is, what's the difference between wake, poweron and wakeorpoweron? Sorry if this is a dumb question! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **wake** wakes up a sleeping Mac, e.g. a Mac that has slept by inactivity or Sleep from the Apple menu.
- **poweron** turns on a powered off Mac, e.g. a Mac that has been shut down from the Shut Down menu from the Apple menu.
- **wakeorpoweron** performs a **wake** if the Mac is sleeping or a **poweron** if the Mac is off.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize it had the power to literally turn on a shut down mac

Comment: @Daniel No problem! The clock is always running. You can even [turn on a powered off Mac on demand over the network](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN).